# Changing through different pieces of text in UITextView/UILabel using next & previous UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, uitextview

Let's say I have 5 pieces of text. I want to use a UITextView or UILabel to display it. I have a Next and Previous button to help me cycle it through. What's the best way to solve this problem?

```
 NSString *text1 = @"Hello World 1"
 NSString *text2 = @"Hello World 2"
 NSString *text3 = @"Hello World 3"
 NSString *text4 = @"Hello World 4"
 NSString *text5 = @"Hello World 5"
```

Comment: have tried anything yet

Comment: I tried using multiple UIbuttons, hiding and showing them. Not a very efficient way to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this solution might be good

in .h file

```
UIButton *nextButton;
UIButton *backButton;
UILabel *textLabel;
NSArray *textStr;
int counter;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    counter=0;

    textStr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Today is rainy", @"Today is sunnt", @"Today is bright", @"Today is gloomy",
    @"Today is beautifyl", nil];

    textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 30, 200, 200)];
    textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self.view addSubview:textLabel];

    nextButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [nextButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(btnClicked:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    nextButton.tag=1;
    [nextButton setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(120.0, 150, 80, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:nextButton];

    backButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [backButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(btnClicked:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    backButton.tag=2;
    [backButton setTitle:@"Previous" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 150, 80.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:backButton];

}
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)btn{



    if (btn.tag==1) {
        NSLog(@"%i", [textStr count]);
        if (counter<[textStr count]-1) {
        counter++;
        NSLog(@"%i", counter);

        textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr objectAtIndex:counter]];
        }
    }
    else{
        if (counter>1) {
        counter--;
            textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr objectAtIndex:counter]];
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That's a good example, which changes the number at the end of the string, but I'm thinking about having different pieces of text like "Today is beautiful" and "Tomorrow is going to rain".

Comment: with that you need to create array of string ... instead of printing number you cant print array at index.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic idea, as the implementation is trivial I won't post the exact code as it will beneficial to learn on your own.

1.Add all your strings to an `NSArray`.

2.Add two buttons to your view with InterfaceBuilder and link to your code.

3.Add a label to your view and link to your code.

4.Create an `int` property and call it `counter`.

5.When the users presses "next" we want to:

> 5.1 Increase the counter by 1.
>
> 5.2 Check to make sure the counter is higher than our array length.
>
> 5.3 If counter > array length then we can set it back to 0 to it loops around.
>
> 5.4 if counter <= array length then we do nothing.
>
> 5.5 grab the string out of the array at the counter index
>
> 5.6 set our label we created in #3 text to the retrieved string.

6.When the user presses "previous" we want to:

> 6.1 Decrease the counter by 1.
>
> 6.2 Check to make sure the counter is >= 0
>
> 6.3 If counter < 0 then we can set it equal to our array length so it loops
>
> 6.4 if counter <= 0 length then we do nothing.
>
> 6.5 grab the string out of the array at the counter index
>
> 6.6 set our label we created in #3 text to the retrieved string.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I managed to get it partially working before I saw Red Devil's solution. Definitely a good learning experience.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it working. I know that it helps me when someone explains the concept rather than just throwing code out.